# Calvinism vs Independent Fundamental Baptist

Tags: reformed-theology, baptist, fundamentalism

I would like to know how does Calvinism differ from Independent Fundamental Baptist teachings. If someone can point main differences in a form of points (f.e. 1st point, 2nd point and so on for Calvinism, and then the same for Baptists). I would also like to know their Definition of Faith and exegesis. I would very much appreciate if you could be specific and thorough in your answers. Thank you.

I know that it could be found on internet, but it is very hard to find the right examples (maybe organizations is a better word; or churches), so I plead for your help.

Comment: Well the whole point of being an independent church is that there is no one that you are responsible to. An individual independent church might come up with their own definition of faith, they might subscribe to a preexisting one, or they might not use any. There are independent Reformed/Calvinist Baptists, and independent Arminian Baptists, and independent modalist Baptists (Oneness Pentecostals). There's really no way to helpfully generalise independent churches, you just have to talk to each one to find out what they believe and teach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a difficult question to answer because IFB is not a denomination, and each church is independent, but there are Fundamentalist fellowships and congresses which have met on rare occasion and have mentioned Calvinism. You could look into resolutions by Fundamental Baptist Fellowship International or World Congress of Fundamentalists. You will find that there can be an acceptable spectrum of Calvinism among fundamentalism, but "hyper-Calvinism" is rejected by IFBs.
https://fbfi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Complete-Resolutions-2010.pdf